# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo in Android after crash

Tags: android, runtime-error

I don't know where this error comes from. It appears when I start the app and crashes!

Error message and stack trace:

```
09-16 17:57:32.022    2441-2441/com.example.tobias.uebung1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tobias.uebung1, PID: 2441
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tobias.uebung1/com.example.tobias.uebung1.main}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xfffffffd
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xfffffffd
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4417)
            at com.example.tobias.uebung1.main.Main(main.java:483)
            at com.example.tobias.uebung1.main.onCreate(main.java:100)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please show the code for line 483 of the `com.example.tobias.uebung1.main` class.

Comment: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xfffffffd Check your strings. Also, Rebuild and Clean the project.

Comment: The error lies on this line 483 in Main class and in package com.example.tobias.uebung1.main

Answer (score 1):

### Read A third Line

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tobias.uebung1/com.example.tobias.uebung1.main}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xfffffffd
```

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException : Means You add Your Activity In AndroidManifest.xml File..

Or check Java File Or XML File name...

Comment: Sorry i what i have to to to slove my problem my Manfest.xml ist at

app/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml

Android studio dont show me an error

Comment: So First Goto Select Your Project Then Goto Project Menu In tab bar Then Clean The Project Because With Out androidManifest Your Project Can't Work... First Try It..

Comment: it's not remove project file just clear a bin File Then Run Project

Comment: Sorry im not the best in coding and german (i am 16) which bin ?

Comment: Thanks for yout help but only this was the error :             twLeben.setText(Leben);
Right:             twLeben.setText("" + Leben);

Leben = int

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89850/discussion-between-maulik-santoki-and-stobiass).